# How to add custom clash detection rules in Navisworks API?

Tags: .net, api, autodesk-navisworks

I am trying to automate clash detection in Navisworks. I've built an Add-ins that can detect clash using Navisworks .Net [API](https://apidocs.co/apps/navisworks/2018/M_Autodesk_Navisworks_Api_Clash_DocumentClashTests_TestsRunAllTests.htm) -

```js
documentClashTest.TestsRunAllTests();
```

I can't find any clue how to add rules to ignore some clashes like Navisworks app-

[image]

How can I add these predefined rules and also my own rules to ignore clashes while detecting clashes?

In the API documentation I've found a class called **Rule** and it's remarks is-

> *Rules are used to apply a certain action or item to a set of items. Such rules are used in TimeLiner and Clash Detective. This class
> enables you to enable or disable a given rule.*

But I can't find how to make some valid rules and then use those.

Comment: Unfortunately, no API with Rule currently. We have wish with the internal ticket ID: NW-44155 . there is not workaround either. Sorry for the bad news to you.

Comment: Thank you very much for you information. @XiaodongLiang